# ag-Grid Change text of Header Group

Tags: aurelia, ag-grid

I am using ag-Grid with Aurelia and wanted to change the text of all group headers when grouping grids.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the `GridApi` via the `api` property on the `ag-grid-aurelia` custom element. From there it's just like it's described in the [docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-api/#columns)